# Downgrading Selenium version in Visual Studio and getting the error messages

Tags: python, selenium

I'm using Pycharm for Selenium and python automation. currently i have selenium version 3.5.0 and successfully  uninstall selenium to downgrade the version. Then Trying to install selenium (low version to higher) I'm getting this message. any help to downgrade selenium version?

Message:

> Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/selenium/

Comment: Are you using NuGet to install the Selenium bits in Visual Studio? You should be able to pick the version you want from the dropdown and install it. Are you sure your driver version supports the browser version?

Comment: Yes, I installed Selenium in Visual Studio. so do I need to uninstall selenium from visual studio too? 

now I tried with new version 3.6.0 selenium, still I'm getting same error message. even I can't use pip to download selenium " pip download selenium"
when I entered > pip list command, I'm getting only these "pip (9.0.1)
setuptools (28.8.0)"